# Observable loaded once, empty after navigating away and back

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a service which is provided in root with an Observable:

```js
organizationSubject = new Subject<Organization>();
organization$ = this.organizationSubject.asObservable();

...

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http
      .get<Organization>('organization')
      .subscribe((organization) => this.organizationSubject.next(organization));
  }
```

In a `OrganizationSettings` component I'm assigning the global Observable to a local Observable in `ngOnInit`:

```js
this.organization$ = this.organizationService.organization$.pipe(
      tap((organization) => {
       // side effects here
      })
```

with the following template:

```html
<div class="mt-6" *ngIf="organization$ | async as organization" [formGroup]="form">
  {{ organization.name }}
</div>
```

When I navigate to a route where I have `OrganizationSettings` for the first time, the page is rendered as expected and I see a div with `Name of my organization`.

Now, when I navigate to another route and come back, I **dont't** see the name of the organization.

Am I missing something here? I'm clueless...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably use a `BehaviorSubject` or a `ReplaySubject(1)` instead of the basic `Subject`; since it won't emit the latest results.

Comment: Thank you for your fast and correct answer. I replaced `Subject` with `ReplaySubject(1)` and now I get the expected results.

Comment: This was due to what is called the "late subscriber" problem if you're interested in learning more about it. An alternative would be to use the shareReplay operator (https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/sharereplay) which could reduce your service code to just    `organization$ = this.http .get<Organization>('organization').pipe(shareReplay(1))`

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the usage of `shareReplay(1)` with hot observables. That will make the observable live "forever", even tho you navigate to another page and may cause memory leaks. Using `publishReplay(1), refCount()` is better. Example: https://blog.strongbrew.io/share-replay-issue/